# how to design an extensible query string sorting method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I need to sort my query string by different parameters.
For example:
`[url]/handler?sort=-key1,key2`
Now, the sorting happens on a list of dicts on each dict's metadata like so:

`sorted(results_list, key=lambda obj:[(-obj["metadata"][x[0]] if x[1] == "desc" else obj["metadata"][x[0]]) for x in sort])`

The parameters are digested from my handler and passed to the logic manager to process the sorting. This code is python 3. I want to make this sorting mechanism more extensible. Currently, it won't allow any sorting to happen that is:

1. Outside the metadata property scope.
2. not a number (for example sorting alphabetically).

I should say that I devoured answers here and saw that many of them suggest to override the cmp function and basically recreate my own sorting module from scratch. I don't think that either what I'm looking for hasn't been done before, or that it merits that kind of implementation.
I could be wrong. We always learn.

So, how should I redesign this code to be more extensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

you should be able to pass a list `SortInstruction` via your API (`handler`).  `get_sorted_list` will take care of the actual sorting.

```
from typing import NamedTuple

lst = [{'meta':{'k':12},'k1': 66,'k2': 'jack'},
       {'meta':{'k':99},'k1': 656,'k2': 'zoo'},
       {'meta':{'k':134},'k1': 166,'k2': 'dan'}]  

class SortInstruction(NamedTuple):
    in_meta_data: bool
    reverse: bool
    field_name: str
    
def get_sorted_list(sort_instructions):
    result = lst
    for si in sort_instructions:
        result = sorted(result, key = lambda x : x[si.field_name] if not si.in_meta_data else x['meta'][si.field_name] , reverse = si.reverse)
    return result
    
sorted_list = get_sorted_list([SortInstruction(True,False,'k'),SortInstruction(False,False,'k1')])

for entry in sorted_list:
    print(entry)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the code more readable and easy for maintenance you'd like to extend the sorting logic and design in a [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) manner. 

I'd advise:

1. `Handler` digests the parameters from the URL to a `context` object that holds them all.
2. `Handler` passes the `context` object to the `LogicManager`, which detects which list to sort and in what way.
3. `LogicManager` send the list to be sorted and the sorting manner as originally described in the URL, to `Sorter` that sortes the lists as described.


   In such a way, each class has its sole propose and the code is easier to maintain. 
   Nonetheless, you can scale sorting by adding more `Sorter` threads or micro-services.